# Applying Green's formula to Petersson inner product.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I'm reading book by Motohashi: spectral theory of Riemann zeta function. And after defining the set  of automorphic functions $L^2(\mathcal{F}, d{\mu})$ with Petersson inner product $$\langle f_1, f_2 \rangle = \int_{\mathcal{F}} f_1(z)\overline{f_2(z)}d\mu(z).$$

Then we claim that by Green's formula we have that $$\langle \Delta f_1, f_2 \rangle = \int_{\mathcal{F}} y^2 \nabla f_1(z) \cdot \overline{f_2(z)} d\mu (z).$$

We apply Green's formula to $$\langle \Delta f_1, f_2 \rangle = \lim_{Y \to \infty} \int_{\mathcal{F_y}} y^2 \nabla f_1(z)\overline{f_2(z)} d\mu (z).$$

$\mathcal{F}_y = \mathcal{F} \cap \{z: Im(z) \leq Y$ }.

$$= \lim_{Y \to \infty} \int_{\mathcal{F_y}} \nabla f_1(z) \cdot \overline{f_2(z)} dxdy - \lim_{Y \to \infty} \int_{\mathcal{\partial F_y}} y \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(x+iY)\overline{f_2(x+iY)} dx.$$

There is more steps given in the book after this and those are enough for me to conclude.

But the question is: What is the Green's formula in this context and how do we apply it here?

Comment: Just a comment since I'm no expert: Usually Green's formula is one of  Green's identities here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_identities); in this context the first one in the section "on manifolds" should give the equality you are wondering about (note that the "closure term" vanishes since $f_1,f_2\in L^2$).

Comment: @mathmax Thanks for your comment, but what do you mean by "closure term"?

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong word, it should be "boundary" not "closure" (English is not my native).